# string format was not recognize as valid dateTime format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

When posting data from view, I send it to the Controller via ajax and split the date time value, then the parameter becomes a string and I want to convert it to my datetime, but I encounter such an error

[image]

Comment: Did you notice the space character at the end of the string?

Answer (score 2):

There is a blank/space at the end of your 'date' string. Use `bgdate.Trim()`. You may also check that bgdate is a non null string and have then a default value with something like `(bgdate == null)?"01-01-1970":bgdate.Trim()`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a white space in your value `08-04-2021` . You should `Trim()` it:

`bgdate.Trim()`